# Automatically download an .aspx generated file

Tags: asp.net, wget, xls

Every week I need to download a file from an .aspx site. On the site I select the start and the end date using basic HTML input form, and I would automate this task so to avoid to have to do it manually. Is there a way to do this using wget? I'm open to other solutions

Comment: potentially yes. Or any other HTTP client. You'd have to test it to see if you can replicate the HTTP request such that the aspx website will accept it - they have a lot of anti-spoofing stuff. Ideally there will be a web API behind the scenes that you can call to request the same information, instead of trying to emulate a human using the GUI client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done with `wget`. Just add `--post-data 'startdate=1.1.2016&enddate=1.1.2017'` parameter. Change field names startdate and enddate to those on remote web form.

You can also try Selenium Web Driver that is used to automate web site testing.